# How many arrangements of 4 letters, with 3 of them being distinct, are there?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I read an example of the "Counting Principle" where we want to find the number of possible ways to rearrange 4 distinct letters chosen from the alphabet.

The answer for this one makes sense. This is a permutation (order matters because the letters must be distinct) and so we just use the formula for a permutation to get $\frac{26!}{22!} =$ whatever.

But, immediately after reading this example I thought of the case where 4 letters are chosen but exactly $1$ of them must be repeated i.e. $3$ distinct with $1$ of the $3$ repeated . This isn't completely a permutation but it also isn't completely a combination... it seems to be a mix.

How can we approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're asking how many rearrangements of $(a,a,b,c)$ there are, you would do what you normally would do and take $4!$. But half of those are double counts, since the $a$ letters are indistinguishable. Our final answer is $4!/2 = 12$.

Comment: The title and text contain slightly different questions. In the title, you require $3$ letters to be distinct. In the text, you relax the requirement of all $4$ being distinct, but it sounds as if they're still allowed to be distinct. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I will assume that you don't allow $4$ distinct. The letter we have $2$ of can be chosen in $26$ ways. For every such choice, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose *where* the doubled letter goes. The first empty spot can then be filled in $25$ ways, and the second in $24$, for a total of $(26)\binom{4}{2}(25)(24)$. If you allow $4$ distinct, add the number you got.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Which part of my question confuses you guys? I reread it and it seemed fine to me - "... only 3 of the letters had to be distinct." Should I change the word "had" to "can"?

Comment: It would be clearer, or at least more standard, if you either said "exactly $3$ are distinct" (if that's what you mean) or "at least $3$ are distinct (if that's what you mean).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok! I edited the question. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the total number of permutations with $3$ letters :
$$\frac{26!}{23!}=15600$$

Then you can add the fourth letter in $4$ different places : 
$$\text{(here)}~A~\text{(here)}~B~\text{(here)}~C~\text{(here)}$$
**But** two of the positions will lead to the same word : in my example, inserting $A$ in the first or second place will create $AABC$.

Therefore, once you know the number of permutations with $3$ letters, just multiply this number by $3 \text{(places)} \times 3\text{(letters)}$ and you've got your total :
$$15600 \times 9 = 140400$$

Comment: This is a different approach than what the others have commented but I like it!

Comment: @DavidSouth: Different, yes, but does it give the right answer?

Comment: @AndréNicolas compared to your answer, it doesn't. Now I have to figure out what the truth is!

Comment: If repeated means occurs twice, the $\binom{4}{2}$ is right. If repeated means sequentially, then instead of $\binom{4}{2}$ one has $3$.

Comment: I just tried to rigouroulsy apply @DavidSouth's rule, in a mathematically simple way. But this methods doesn't stand if we're not in this very particular case he describes